# Namenode and Datanode are not starting in hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, terminal

I installed hadoop 2.6.0 in my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04LTS. I started the hadoop daemons by running start-all.sh. But when I type jps only 4 are running

```
10545 SecondaryNameNode
10703 ResourceManager
11568 Jps
10831 NodeManager
```

Previously only datanode only was not running so I deleted the tmp folder and created it again. Now namenode and datanode both are not running. I also checked whether 50070 and 50075 are being used by any other processes but there are no processes using them.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       52304       6129/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       70108       10545/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       50441       6129/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::8033                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       70199       10703/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8040                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       74863       10831/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8042                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       71055       10831/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::46573                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       74854       10831/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       71049       10703/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::13562                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       71054       10831/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8030                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       72716       10703/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8031                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       72175       10703/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::8032                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       72182       10703/java
```

This is what I have in my datanode logs:

```
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = srimanth/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.6.0
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0-tests.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-tests.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r e3496499ecb8d220fba99dc5ed4c99c8f9e33bb1; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2014-11-13T21:10Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_65
************************************************************/
2015-01-27 19:30:29,640 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2015-01-27 19:30:31,491 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2015-01-27 19:30:32,241 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2015-01-27 19:30:32,655 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2015-01-27 19:30:32,656 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2015-01-27 19:30:32,672 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Configured hostname is srimanth
2015-01-27 19:30:32,707 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting DataNode with maxLockedMemory = 0
2015-01-27 19:30:32,826 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened streaming server at /0.0.0.0:50010
2015-01-27 19:30:32,838 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Balancing bandwith is 1048576 bytes/s
2015-01-27 19:30:32,838 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Number threads for balancing is 5
2015-01-27 19:30:33,233 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2015-01-27 19:30:33,246 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.datanode is not defined
2015-01-27 19:30:33,284 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2015-01-27 19:30:33,291 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context datanode
2015-01-27 19:30:33,291 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2015-01-27 19:30:33,292 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2015-01-27 19:30:33,346 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: addJerseyResourcePackage: packageName=org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.web.resources;org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources, pathSpec=/webhdfs/v1/*
2015-01-27 19:30:33,357 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 50075
2015-01-27 19:30:33,358 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2015-01-27 19:30:34,395 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:50075
2015-01-27 19:30:34,443 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: dnUserName = srimanth
2015-01-27 19:30:34,443 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: supergroup = supergroup
2015-01-27 19:30:34,611 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2015-01-27 19:30:34,690 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 50020
2015-01-27 19:30:34,938 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened IPC server at /0.0.0.0:50020
2015-01-27 19:30:34,993 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Refresh request received for nameservices: null
2015-01-27 19:30:35,078 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting BPOfferServices for nameservices: <default>
2015-01-27 19:30:35,119 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 starting to offer service
2015-01-27 19:30:35,139 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2015-01-27 19:30:35,139 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 50020: starting
2015-01-27 19:30:36,112 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: DataNode version: -56 and NameNode layout version: -60
2015-01-27 19:30:36,187 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /usr/local/hadoop/hdfs/datanode/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 13180@srimanth
2015-01-27 19:30:36,210 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Exiting. 
java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /usr/local/hadoop/hdfs/datanode: namenode clusterID = CID-9748dc33-5035-4bcc-9b51-cb75e0a7eadc; datanode clusterID = CID-41e9d369-787a-4595-8827-6bb3277787e9
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:646)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.addStorageLocations(DataStorage.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:828)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-01-27 19:30:36,252 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
2015-01-27 19:30:36,360 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned)
2015-01-27 19:30:38,360 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
2015-01-27 19:30:38,366 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
2015-01-27 19:30:38,371 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at srimanth/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

I would appreciate some help. thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `hdfs-site.xml` file there should be `dfs.data.dir` property that points to a local directory. Delete everything **under** the directory and **not** the directory itself. Careful!! if you have any data on hdfs you will lose all of it.

Answer (score 5):

Set the `dfs.namenode.name.dir` and `dfs.datanode.data.dir` in `hdfs-site.xml`
and it looks like this:

```
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>/<local-dir path>/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>/<local-dir path>r/datanode</value>
 </property>
```

If already  you have this folders in your directory then delete them and Restart your `NameNode`

Answer (score 3):

1. you should configure `hadoop.tmp.dir` in your `core-site.xml` file, and change its permissions to be accessible.
2. you should configure `dfs.data.dir` property in your `hdfs-site.xml` file to point to a local directory, also change the permissions of that directory to be accessible.
3. you should configure `dfs.name.dir` property in your `hdfs-site.xml` file to point to a local directory, also change the permissions of that directory to be accessible.

After doing above steps try formatting hdfs and starting hadoop. **Note** that you may not necessarily want to do the third step since your NameNode is already running.

Upon executing jps command you probably should be able to see your DataNode up and running...

```
33584 ResourceManager
29907 
33719 Jps
33275 NameNode
33469 SecondaryNameNode
33677 NodeManager
33359 DataNode
```

Comment: `dfs.datanode.data.dir`, `dfs.namenode.name.dir` are correct. See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Answer (score 0):

Namenode cluster id and datanode cluster id should be same...

If not then the error message will occurs. go to dfs.namenode.name.dirlocation>/current/version.

If you cant find the location. go to log file and then see the datanode logs. You can see the location.

If datanode and /current/version. in that you will see the cluster id.

If both are same then you there is no error message..

If not stop the nodes and then format namenode Or Delete the location of the file and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

We will get the above error if we format the namenode when cluster is active .

Say you have installed hadoop on your cluster and suddenly on one day you have an error and formated the namenode. Whenever we do a namenode format a new clusterid and bunch of other parameters are set in VERSION file. But for normal functioning all these need to be same across the cluster. But this consistency will be lost if you have formated the namenode when cluster was active.

To fix this error, you need to do below steps :
1) Shutdown all the nodes in cluster
2) replace the  version file in namenode data directory with the one present in the other nodes.
3) Start namenode first and then once everything is fine in the namenode logs, start all the other nodes.

Note: This might corrupt your data, be carefull. Remember not to reformat namenode, this will cause a loss in data

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem , the issue is I created a folder to save hdfs data and not given permissions to user through which I'm executing start-all.sh or start-dfs.sh script.So,please do check permissions to the folder for particular user.

Comment: This should be a comment